# M50 Mounting maximum weight

Tags: lens, canon, troubleshooting, lens-mount, lens-adapter

I have a canon m50, and an adapter + 55-250 f4 lens, the total weight of the lens and adapter is 500gram, is it safe to install a tripod on the camera body, because my mount adapter is broken

Comment: Probably hard to express as a maximum weight because leverage plays a key role here.... 500 grams on a 2 meter long tube would likely NOT be good for your lens mount, OTOH there are probably native lenses for EF-M now that are far heavier than 500g.

Comment: These other questions don't directly answer yours, but are definitely related: [Are there any official specifications regarding the torque for camera mounts?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/52394), [Can I hang a heavy lens vertically from the body?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/117125), [Can I damage my camera's lens mount by lifting it with a super-tele lens attached?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/97487), [Can a lens be too heavy for a given camera?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/94550)

Comment: I'd be concerned If using a much heavier lens, such as a 1500g 70-200/2.8. But 500g is still relatively light. Depending on exactly what you mean by "my mount adapter is broken", though, I'm not sure I'd trust either end to not be supported. What do you mean when you say, "... because my mount adapter is broken?"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific max weight for the lens mount, as such, I've never really seen that on any camera I've owned (modern or film) as typically heavy lenses should be supported directly and not via the camera body.

While the M50 mount is welded to the inner metal frame, this not is heavy duty. I would not recommend supporting a heavy lens with the body on a tripod (or on a carry with a strap). Now, is that lens too heavy? My rule of thumb on this is based on whether or not the lens is equipped with its own tripod collar. AFAIK, yours is not, but it's also not specifically designed for your camera. My feeling is err on the side of caution and use the lens in a supported manner.

Comment: I'd be fairly confident that when Canon designed the EOS-M mount and system with plans to make EF lenses adaptable to EF-M bodies they took this into account with regards to the design limits of the flange mount ring for the EOS-M system. As your first paragraph alludes to, the point at which the entire combination should be supported primarily by the lens rather than by the body will be reached due to maximizing camera stability when shooting long before the load limits of the mount rings themselves are challenged. After all, there are EF bodies that weigh 14 to 54 oz. all with the same ring.